# Can I safely connect audio output from USB soundcard to TRRS input of Raspberry Pi

Tags: audio

I am piping audio from my MacBook into my Raspberry Pi 3B.

```
MacBook -> Headphone output of USB soundcard -> TRRS cable -> RasberryPi jack input
```

I am then running it through a DSP algorithm which should decode the signal perfectly.

However, on my setup it is failing to decode the signal.

A couple of my teammates have it working (but sporadically). [EDIT: Turns out their setup is different, see answer].

Is there anything I need to take into account here?

Do I need to insert some resistor/capacitor circuitry?

Comment: The Raspberry Pi has **NO** "jack input" - it is OUTPUT only.

Comment: `it is frequently failing to decode the signal` - by frequently you mean **always**

Comment: @Milliways Two engineers on the team are experiencing intermittent success, so it must be possible to configure it as input.

Comment: The circuit is published. The Pi has **ABSOLUTELY** no analog input so it is impossible.

Comment: Thanks @Milliways
That was the problem. My route was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

(Thanks @Milliways)
I was using an incorrect route.

The RaspberryPi has no audio input. It is not possible to configure the jack for input. It is OUTPUT only.

The correct route is:

```
MacBook AudioJack -> TRRS cable -> MicIn-of-USB-Soundcard -> Rπ USB
```

Now my Rπ is able to decode the signal.

The problem of intermittency experienced by one developer is likely in the `Laptop Jack Spkr <--> USB SoundCard Mic` step, and therefore not a Rπ issue.